# Android AsyncTask crash on multiple internet downloads

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My code pulls a JSON from a Server. The JSON has Image URL's. I parse the JSON and download the Images from the URL's in the JSON into a Bitmap Hashtable to stop multiple downloads of the same image. When i run this on UI thread, the app slows down but works. On moving it to a AsyncTask, the app crashes with a FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

What could have possibly gone wrong?

Here is the Async code http://pastebin.com/isDgENkJ

Comment: Show us your `AsyncTask` code.

Comment: also post the logcat error to get a clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `class` declaration to:

```
public class GetMapsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, CustomItemizedOverlay>{
```

and your method of `doInBackgournd()` should look like:

```
protected CustomItemizedOverlay doInBackground(Void... v){
```

remove this line inside `doInBackgournd()`:

```
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

and put this line instead of `return null;` at the end inside `doInBackgournd()`:

```
return itemizedOverlay;
```

and your method of `onPostExecute()` should look like:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CustomItemizedOverlay overlay) {
     mapOverlays.add(overlay);
}
```

if still you see any `Exception` then post your logcat also.